# Fit image completely inside Konva Stage - Layer - Rect

Tags: reactjs, react-konva

Trying to put a background image into a `<Stage>` using a `Rect` inside a `Layer` and `fillPaternImage` property of `Rect`. The background image does take the entire space of the stage but it gets cropped. How do you fit/cover the entire space of the stage while preserving the aspect ratio of the image(secondary)?

Main Code Fragment

```
componentDidUpdate(props)
{
    const image = new window.Image();
    image.src = this.props.backgroundImage; // path to the image
    image.height = image.naturalHeight;
    image.width = image.naturalWidth;

    image.onload = () => {
        this.setState({
            fillPatternImage: image
        })
    }
}

<Stage
    width={1000}
    height={1000}
    style={{ border: '1px solid grey' }}
>
    <Layer>
        <Rect
            x={0}
            y={0}
            width={1000}
            height={1000}
            listening={false}
            fillPatternImage={this.state.fillPatternImage}
        >
        </Rect>
    </Layer>
</Stage>
```

Through the above code, the web page looks like this:
[image]

Actual image:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `fillPatternScaleX` and `fillPatternScaleY` attributes to change the size of the image.

```js
const width = 1000;
const height = 1000;

const imageWidth = this.state.fillPatternImage?.width || width;
const imageHeight = this.state.fillPatternImage?.height || height;

const scaleX = width / imageWidth;
const scaleY = height / imageHeight;
const scale = Math.max(scaleX, scaleY);
return (
  <Rect
    width={width}
    height={height}
    fillPatternImage={this.state.fillPatternImage}
    fillPatternScaleX={scale}
    fillPatternScaleY={scale}
  >
);
```